# I'm trying to get a certain URL's cookies in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I need to get the cookies from the resources too.

I need every single cookie in the resource to output into console or output onto an alert.

Here is the code:

```
function getAll(port, message) {
        chrome.tabs.get(1, function(tab) {
            var url = "www.roblox.com";
            console.log("Looking for cookies on: " + url);
            chrome.cookies.getAll({
                url : url
            })
        });
    }
```

This is all I have so far

Here is an image of the resources:

[image]

Comment: you are using chrome api in a wrong way, you'd better read the doc more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

1: chrome.cookies API can only used in background scripts

2: you have to declare domain permission in the manifest.json

3: you do not need to query the tab before get the cookies.

so, here is the manifest.json slice:

```
  "permissions": [
          "cookies",
          "*://*/*"
        ],
```

then in your background script, it should like this:
var domainThatYouWantToGetCookies = "www.roblox.com"

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({
                domain : domainThatYouWantToGetCookies  //use domain not url
            }, function(cookies){
                   console.log(cookies);
    });
```

you can see the console output in the background console.

Comment: could you link a download? it still isn't working for me